# How to git push using git-emacs?

Tags: git, emacs, lisp

I am using the git-emacs to submit code to github throug Emacs.
It is ok for `add` and `commit`, but it seems that git-emacs do not support the `git push` operation. When I type `M-x git-push`, it responds with "no such command".

Comment: You can run `git push` in `eshell`.

Answer (score 8):

You're right, it doesn't. However, [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) can push.

Comment: so i turn to magit , but i still fail to push , it is ok to stage and commit , but when i type P P to do a git push , it just said: "git push -v ...... " in the console , it did not really push anything into the repository, could you help with this also?

Comment: There is a problem with github: https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/433 Check by pressing `$` whether Magit hangs on login. Update to newest Magit, and if this doesn't help -- well pushing is just a couple of keystrokes in the shell...

Answer (score 7):

Newer versions of Emacs provide the command:

```
C-x v P
```

longer version:

```
M-x vc-push
```

(as noted by @CAT0). If your version of Emacs doesn't support that command, try:

```
M-& git push [Enter]
```

longer version:

```
M-x async-shell-command [Enter] git push [Enter]
```

As pointed out by @mariotomo this is better than the synchronous version below because it opens a buffer for the output.

```
M-! git push [Enter]
```

longer version:

```
M-x shell-command [Enter] git push [Enter]
```

(`M-` is short for "Meta key" which can be `Esc` or `Alt` or `Ctrl+[`).

(and if you're on Windows and hesitate to use the shell which goes to a nasty DOS shell by default, try running Emacs as `emacs-w32` from Cygwin, things will be saner).

Comment: even better, use `M-&` so emacs won't be stuck waiting for git to complete, and a buffer will appear with the output of the command.

Answer (score 3):

In emacs 25 (maybe also earlier) there is the command

> vc-push

which does exactly what it should. It is bound to
C-x v P

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate side effect of the fact the built-in Emacs VCS support(`vc-mode`) is mostly built for tools like cvs, subversion, etc that have a totally different workflow. DVCS support was added fairly soon (in Emacs 23). I hope `vc-mode` will be improved in the near future. Until then...

As @khagler said Magit supports `git push`. Another solid option for you to explore is [Egg](https://github.com/bogolisk/egg).

Answer (score 1):

By git-emacs, you can push in the following way:

1. `M-x git-cmd`, which is bound to `C-x g .` ( In `git-status` window it is bound to `.`)
2. type in `push`